# Combobox in Datagrid view vb.net

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, combobox, datagrid

i know this question is so old and had been asked so many times , but i didn't find the exact thing i want.
i used to have some comboboxes and textboxes that the user will fill and choose data one by one  and at the enter press on the last box, all data are added as a new row to the datagrid.
now what i want is to make the first row in my datagrid replace all these boxes.
but am already stuck on the first item.

i want the first column to be a combobox, but it gets its values from a SQL database based on a query that i write. in the combobox i want to type what i want to search and select ( as dropdown style in a normal combobox).

---

Something like the code below, but for a combobox in the datagridview.

```
 Dim sqlquery = " SELECT  m.accno,m.accname
              FROM masteraccount m
              where accname like '%TextBox3.Text%'
                    or accno like '%TextBox3.Text%'  "

        Using comm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlquery, SQL.SQLCon)
            Dim rs As SqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader
            Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
            dt.Load(rs)
            ListBox1.DataSource = dt
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "acc"
            ComboBox1.ValueMember = "acc"

        End Using
```

Comment: You have to add a column as combobox. I am sure you can find enough examples here on stackoverflow.com

Comment: yes there are , but no one shows how i can handle a sql relation as i want exactly.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the code according to your requirements. When you type or select an item from the combobox it populates the other cells. Both methods have the same functionality. Check the modified code below.

```
Private Sub FillComboBox()
    If cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then cn.Close()
    cn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Juan\Documents\NorthwindSample.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
    cn.Open()

    cmb.Name = "cmb"
    cmb.HeaderText = "Employee"

    'query that retrieves all the employee names
    Dim sqlquery As String = "Select [last name] & ' ' &  [first name] as Name " &
             "From employees order by [last name]"

    'add the query results to the combobox cell in datagridview
    Using comm As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlquery, cn)
        Dim rs As OleDbDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader
        dtable = New DataTable
        dtable.Load(rs)
        cmb.DataSource = dtable
        cmb.DisplayMember = dtable.Columns.Item(0).ColumnName
        cmb.ValueMember = dtable.Columns.Item(0).ColumnName
        DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb)
    End Using

    'create other columns
    CreateColumns()
End Sub
'Procedure to fill the other cells
Sub FillCells(cmbValue As String, conn As OleDbConnection)

    'query that retrieves the rest of the fields that matches with the combobox value
    Dim sqlquery2 As String = "Select [Last Name] & ' ' & [First Name] as Name, [e-mail address], [job title], city 
          From employees
    Where [Last Name] & ' ' & [First Name] = '" & cmbValue & "'"

    'Assigns query results to datatable 
    Using comm2 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlquery2, conn)
        Dim rs As OleDbDataReader = comm2.ExecuteReader
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        dt.Load(rs)

        'creates a datarow for the datatable
        Dim dtRow As DataRow

        Dim email As String = ""
        Dim jobtitle As String = ""
        Dim city As String = ""

        'assigns datarow items to variables

        For Each dtRow In dt.Rows

            dtRow.Field(Of String)(dt.Columns.Item(1))
            email = dtRow.Item(1)
            jobtitle = dtRow.Item(2)
            city = dtRow.Item(3)

        Next

        'assigns the index of the current row to the variable
        Dim currentRow As Integer

        currentRow = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index

        'fills the cells with the values
        DataGridView1.Item(1, currentRow).Value = email
        DataGridView1.Item(2, currentRow).Value = jobtitle
        DataGridView1.Item(3, currentRow).Value = city
        dt = Nothing
    End Using

End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, 
        e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing

    'REMEMBER TO CHANGE THE COLUMN INDEX NUMBER TO YOUR COMBOBOX INDEX!!
    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(e.Control, ComboBox)
        combo.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown

        If (combo IsNot Nothing) Then
            ' Remove an existing event-handler, if present, to avoid adding multiple handlers when the editing control is reused.
            RemoveHandler combo.SelectionChangeCommitted, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted)
            RemoveHandler combo.TextChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_TextChanged)
            RemoveHandler combo.KeyDown, New KeyEventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_KeyDown)

            ' Add the event handler.
            AddHandler combo.SelectionChangeCommitted, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted)
            AddHandler combo.TextChanged, New EventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_TextChanged)
            AddHandler combo.KeyDown, New KeyEventHandler(AddressOf ComboBox_KeyDown)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_SelectionChangeCommitted(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    FillCells(combo.Text, cn)
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox_TextChanged(sender As Object,
                 e As EventArgs)
    Dim combo As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    FillCells(combo.Text, cn)
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    Select Case (e.KeyCode)
        Case Keys.Tab
            e.Equals(Keys.Return)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks it worked better than other codes, but still cant search through combobox.
if you have 1000 employee, i want to show them according to what i typle ( query that retrieves all the employee names
    Dim sqlquery As String = "Select [last name] and [first name] where [firstname] like ' combobox.text %' "